# Cannot able to create Android 24" tablet as tablet device in emulator - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-screen-support

I am trying to create Android Tablet 24" with resolution 1920 X 1080 in android studio. Every time I create it for tablet, it is displaying the device in TV. I run the device and I get only as TV emulator. I need it as Tablet.

[image: Configuration for Tablet Image]

Comment: For testing "ldpi" resolution? For testing "xlarge" screen sizes? What other point is there in creating a 24" inch *tablet emulator*? I mean, you still get the same room on the screen as a Nexus 5 which is a phone...

Comment: @EugenPechanec You mean I have to give only screen resolution 1920 x 1080, don't bother about screen size?

Comment: It depends. But when was the last time you saw an 24 *inch* tablet? 7 inch devices and larger are considered "xlarge". I really recommend this article http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html